# ASP.NET MVC Model split across multiple Partial Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, model-validation

I'm developing a MVC 3 Razor Web App, in which details of multiple categories of objects are stored. (Vehicles, Houses, Instruments etc) . All the objects share some common data (Title, Description etc) And some details which are specific to the category in which it belongs to.   The Category list is expected to grow and in view of reducing maintainability we hope to reuse the same Add Object wizard . The wizard is based on the following implementation.

http://afana.me/post/create-wizard-in-aspnet-mvc-3.aspx

In the Multiple step wizard process , the final step allows the user to enter the category specific details (Model, Make, VIN etc for a Vehicle). Currently i've envisioned this final step as a Partial View with AJAX. So we will actually be having mulltiple partial views that reflect the specific category, but share the rest of the wizard code.

My generic model object is like this

```
public class AssetView
{
    [Required]      
    public string Title
     {
        get;
        set;
     }

    [Required]
    public string Description
    {
     get;
      set;
     }

    // Few more generic fields here

    public SpecificAsset AssetDetails { get; set; }
}
```

The complex property AssetDetails is represented by each type of partial view. So the PartialView "MotorDetails" will contain a strongly typed model of type MotorAsset which is declared as below.

```
  public class MotorAsset : SpecificAsset
    {
        [Required]
        public string Transmission
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Required]
        public string Make
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
     }
```

The actual validation is far complex , but i've omitted these so that's easier to understand.

The Main Wizard page is declared as

```
    @model AssetView

  .....

  <div class="wizard-step">
     ....
  </div>
  <div class="wizard-step">
     ....
  </div>
  <div class="wizard-step">
      @{Html.RenderPartial("_MotorCreate", Model.AssetDetails);
  </div>
```

The Motor Partial View as

```
 @model MotorAsset
```

My question is how can i accomplish model validation in this scenario (or is it possible to use), as the final step is not in the view page but on a partial view .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why wouldn't you resort to the simple classes inheritance (OOP paradigm) rather than having a property AssetDetails on your AssetView?

Instead of what you now have you should rather declare the

AssetView (generic properties)
-> MotorView inheriting AssetView (specific properties)

Like this:

```
public class AssetView {     
    [Required]           
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description     { get; set; }      

    // Few more generic fields here
}

public class MotorView : AssetView {
    ...
}

@model MotorView    // you still have access to the AssetView's properties in your view and in your controller actions
```

If you want to leave it the way you have now, then use `EditorFor()` and create an `EditorFor` template in the Shared folder and strong type it to `MotorAsset` (or `SpecificAsset`, if you want it even more generic).

Then render it out like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.AssetDetails)
```

This will enable the controller to validate it and autobind it to the property in your `AssetView`.
HTH

Comment: if i do this.. I will not be able to reuse the wizard UI , i will have to create one for each type of category.

Comment: which will be better, cleaner and more maintainable in my opinion. But, if you want to leave it the way it is, you can have your validation and binding solved by using EditorFor() instead of RenderPartial(). See the updated answer.

Comment: we will be having more than 20 types of categories and thats just for now.. that is expected to grow further , so no its not maintainable. I dont think editorFor can be used cos the type of "AssetDetails" is "SpecificAsset" . the type will dynamically change according to the category in use.

Comment: RenderPartial() won't prefix textbox's (and other HTML input controls) IDs and name attribute's with "AssetDetails". Therefore autobinding will fail and subsequently validation will fail too. RenderPartial() is great for static content but I've been converting to EditorFor() for rendering editing subforms for some time now.

Comment: point taken. i'm not saying i should be using RenderPartial(), i'm just saying that using EditorFor will not work for my scenario, since the Property AssetDetails is declared as "SpecificAsset" type, depending on the object being added the type will change dynamically to "MotorView" , "HomeView"  etc. so if i use EditorFor in this case it will look for a Partial View with type "SpecificAsset" which is just a empty type.

Comment: I won't say that is true or not but it might be worth checking that out to be sure. Cause I haven't yet and it would be interesting to know whether it can pick up the type at runtime.

Comment: You will also have to figure out how to select the RenderPartial control name at runtime because currently you have it hardcoded. And in the control itself you can also try prefixing the name attributes with "AssetDetails_" and ID attributes with "AssetDetails.". Maybe then the binding will work. But it's a hack.

Comment: Turns out EditorFor does infer the runtime type of the property and renders the editor template correctly. thanks!!

Comment: It looks like i spoke too soon, though the view does get rendered according to the type. i cannot access the dynamic type (MotorAsset) in the controller. the type is still "Specific Asset".

Comment: yeah but if it really is MotorAsset "under the hood" then you should be able to explicitly cast it to MotorAsset. Try that.

Comment: yep..i tried that b4.. multiple ways by direct cast as well casting it to object and casting again. both fail. tried the "Is" keyword to determine type at controller, and it says its still a "Specific Asset" type.

Comment: hmm that's strange because your main wizard page is typed to AssetView and your EditorFor templates should be typed each one to its specific type so it actually does not reference SpecificAsset anywhere.

Comment: but "AssetDetails" property is still declared as "SpecificAsset" in the AssetView Class. although the EditorFor correctly picks up the runtime type, the controller seems unable to identify the type.

Comment: You mean the controller to which you post after each step? Do you bind to AssetView? If so and if the AssetDetails property after POST is not null, can you check if the property holds the subproperties of specific type?

Comment: I dont do a POST on each step.. just hiding Div's using Jquery , see my original POST for the link that shows how the wizard is implemented. its a single View which uses the AssetView as the model. i do a form.submit() on the final step, in the controller action that handles it the "AssetDetails" property is shown to be of type "SpecificAsset" which is just an empty type with no sub properties. it is here that casting also fails.

Comment: Does your binding even work? Is it just the AssetDetails property that is empty and other properties (like Title) have values or all the values are missing? I think all in all your binding is failing.

Comment: yes its only the AssetDetails property that is empty. the AssetView properties (Brief, title etc) has the content that was entered in the wizard.

Comment: Ok. Please inspect the FormCollection collection if values are there. If they are, then the default binder couldn't bind them. If they are not, then you have something wrong in the view and values did not even get POSTed (missing controls or something).

Comment: The formsCollection holds all values, the "AssetDetails" specific properties like "Transmission", "Make" are in the forms collection prefixed by "AssetDetails_", probably the reason why they didnt bind.

Comment: I think you will be able to use that collection to achieve what you want and we should wrap up this discussion now.

Comment: checking the forms collection is not practical, cos i have more than 20 categories to consider for nw. the solution is yet incomplete, i have re-posted this with a summary.